# unbinding e.preventDefault from another function to forward to link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get this working on the first click? When the link is clicked it seems to unbind the event, but does not forward to the link till the second click. Is there a way to have it forward to the link on the first click unbinding the `e.preventDefault` from the click function?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/542fnbbL/

jQuery:

```
var clickTime = function(e){
    $('a').unbind('click').submit();
};
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickTime();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking for [**jQuery one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Please explain better what you're trying to achieve.  If you just need something to happen once, on first click, then see jQuery `.one()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you need it for, but retriggering a click is not done using `submit`, so pass your element along, `unbind` it and the immediately follow the link.

```
var clickTime = function(element){
    $(element).unbind('click');
    window.location.href = $(element).attr("href");
};
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickTime(this);
});
```

Here an easy bit of HTML to test it's validity without having it following an actual link:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('here')">link </a>
```

But what do you need this for? You could as well do everything you want to do before triggering your event.preventDefault(), as such:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do Stuff Here
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Whats the separate function for?

Comment: I have some validation going on in my page, which happens in that separate function along with an ajax call. I have a few separate things going on in the click function also. But if all goes well in the called function with my ajax, then with will forward to the link

Comment: @Chipe, if you have other things going on then you need to show them in your question.

Comment: I do apologize for that. I didnt see all the varied answers that could be associated with what I was asking. But thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I misundestood your answer in the first time.
Here it is:

Code:

```
$('a').one('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Well, I am first preventing the default on the initial click of the anchor, in the function it calls to I have other things that could be done that will not call to the click event, but if certain things are met on the page, then I want to unbind the e.preventDefault and then forward to the link

Comment: Why would you need to do all that when jQuery provides [the `.one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?

Comment: @Sparky please read my original answer before downvoting me. thanks

Comment: Please do not honestly expect people to review revision history... if it's important to mention, then keep it in the answer.  Based on the code in your revised answer, there is still no reason you cannot use `.one()`.